# Turning off animations on bezier paths in swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, bezier

I'm trying to manipulate the dimensions and appearance of a vector graphic drawn with bezier paths in swift and all of them are animated by default. (i.e. on CATransform3DMakeScale() it animates the size change even though it's not asked to. And when .hidden is used, it fades rather than disappears). I would like to know if there is a way I can turn off such animations for all vectors.

Comment: I assume you read the ["how to ask questions on Stackoverflow"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), but if you haven't, please do. There's a fair bit of information missing here (for instance, at the very least show [minimal code that demonstrates this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)),